# Alinear en el centro de un Anchorpane un FXML incluido

Tags: javafx, fxml

Estoy intentando centrar un FXML incluido mediante "fx:include" en un Anchorpane.
He intentado mediante CSS, pero parece que no funciona.
¿Existe alguna manera de centrar el contenido en el Anchorpane?

Un saludo.

Ejemplo codigo:

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
         <fx:include source="EjemploView.fxml" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```